# Регулярное выражение для проверки порта

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Уважаемые, нужно регулярное выражения для валидации порта. То есть, целое значение от 0 до 65535. Обещаю больше не задавать глупых вопросов и выучить `regex`.

Comment: А правильно-ли в подобном случае использовать регулярку? Имхо - нет.

Comment: Ок, тогда как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не будем спрашивать, почему вы не можете перевести строку в число и сравнить, а попробуем составить регулярку :)

```
^(([0-9]{1,4})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(655[0-2][0-9])|(6553[0-5]))$
```

Принцип здесь такой: берете [regexp редактор](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) и вводите тестовые значение, например:

```
1
23
800
8080
60000
65001
65532
65535
71234 -- не должно находить!
```

А дальше по частям сочиняем регулярное выражение. Сначала нужно проверить четырехзначные числа (до 9999), они могут быть любые `([0-9]{1,4})`. Затем пятизначные до 59999 `([1-5][0-9]{4})`, затем до 64999 `(6[0-4][0-9]{3})`, затем до 65499
`(65[0-4][0-9]{2})`, затем до 65529 `(655[0-2][0-9])`,  затем до 65535 `(6553[0-5])`

Объединяем группы с помощью `|`

Comment: А почему бы вместо этого не воспользоваться /^(\d+)$/ и сравнением с 65535 в Groups? Всяко наглядней и короче.

Comment: @klopp, Можно даже не париться с регулярными выражениями, когда строка состоит только из числа, а просто преобразовать строку в число стандартными средствами языка.

Comment: Строка может состоять из любых символов(ну сами знаете, юзеры всякое могут ввести))) , а Int.TryParse("+100"); возвращает true. ОЧЕНЬ было важно что бы метод возвращал false при строке "+ someInt".

Comment: @dima_kot, в таком случае лучше поступить как предлагает @klopp, проверить, что строка состоит только из цифр, штатными средствами привести к числу и сравнить с 65535.  
Данное мной и @tolyandre решения слишком неоптимальны по скорости и являются индийским кодом применительно конкретно к Вашей задаче.

Comment: да. На шарпе эта проверка примерно так будет выглядеть:
private int GetPort(string str) {
 if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^\d+$")) {
  int port = int.Parse(str);
  if ((port > 0) && (port <= 65535))
   return port;
 }
 return -1;
}

Answer (score 2):

У меня такой вариант для PCRE:

```
preg_replace("/(?!\d)(?:(?:[0-9]{5}(?<![7-9]\.{4})(?<!6[6-9]\.{3})(?<!65[6-9]\.{2})(?<!655[4-9]\.)(?<!6553[6-9]))|[0-9]{1,4})(?!\d)/", "XX", " 65536 ");
```

При этом регулярному выражению не важно в каком месте строки находится число.